# error installing libgd in mac 10.9

Tags: macos, perl, gd, libraries, circos

I'm trying to install libgd on my mac OSX 10.9 following the instructions here (https://mikewest.org/2007/04/installing-libgd-from-source-on-os-x) and peaking on some more info here ([Installing GD library for perl on MacOSX 10.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261921/installing-gd-library-for-perl-on-macosx-10-6)).

the main goal is to be able to install and use Circos.

i followed all the steps to install the various libraries libpgn, pibjpeg and freetype using mainly `./configure && make && make sudo install`...however
1) the `./congigure` command from libgd does not find the libraries that I just installed and what I get is the following:

```
** Configuration summary for libgd 2.1.0:

   Support for Zlib:                 yes
   Support for PNG library:          no
   Support for JPEG library:         no
   Support for VPX library:          no
   Support for TIFF library:         no
   Support for Freetype 2.x library: no
   Support for Fontconfig library:   no
   Support for Xpm library:          no
   Support for pthreads:             yes
```

i read the README file (yeeee) suggesting to use `--with-png=myDirectory --with-freetype=myDir` etc..i did that (not sure if it made a difference) but when I get to the `make` command I get the following error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___sincos_stret", referenced from:
      _gdImageCopyRotated in gd.o
      _gdAffineRotate in gd_matrix.o
      _gdImageRotateNearestNeighbour in gd_interpolation.o
      _gdImageRotateGeneric in gd_interpolation.o
      _gdImageRotateBilinear in gd_interpolation.o
      _gdImageRotateBicubicFixed in gd_interpolation.o
      _filter_bessel in gd_interpolation.o
      ...
  "_iconv", referenced from:
      _do_convert in gdkanji.o
  "_iconv_close", referenced from:
      _do_convert in gdkanji.o
  "_iconv_open", referenced from:
      _do_convert in gdkanji.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [libgd.la] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

...more extensive in pastie: http://pastebin.com/BuvskMPe

so I'm stuck, I'm reading online and it looks like it has to do with Xcode and gcc but I can't find out how to troubleshoot this.

any help would be awesome!!

Comment: Looks like an issue because you are trying to compile  with compiler clang(llvm) that comes along with Xcode. The open source packages/libraries (libgd here) usually compile well and are tested with with gcc.Apple deprecated the gcc compiler in OS X 10.8.I am not sure whether clang supports the new C++ standard (TR1), that defines the hash dictionary ("unordered_map").

You need to install g++ yourself via macports or homebrew or get it from gcc.org to build libgd.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I successfully installed it using homebrew. It was as simple as:

brew install gd

This installed lib-gd version 2.1.0_1.