# Installing Circos: Problems installing GD module on Mac OS

Tags: homebrew, gd, osx-yosemite, circos

I would like to install Circos. I followed the [instructions](http://circos.ca/documentation/tutorials/configuration/installation/) on Circos website. In particular, I checked for missing perl modules. I'm missing several of them:

```
missing            Font::TTF::Font
missing            GD
missing            GD::Polyline
missing            SVG
missing            Statistics::Basic
missing            Text::Format
```

So I followed again the [instructions about Installing Perl Modules on Mac OS X](http://circos.ca/documentation/tutorials/configuration/perl_and_modules/) on Circos website. Specifically, I followed the [detailed instructions in Paulo Nuin's blog post](http://zientzilaria.herokuapp.com/blog/2012/06/03/installing-circos-on-os-x/). Freetype and Fontconfig were missing and I installed them.

Now, when I run the configuration for libgd-2.2.1, I get this configuration summary:

```
Support for Zlib: yes
Support for PNG library: yes
Support for JPEG library: yes
Support for WebP library: no
Support for TIFF library: no
Support for Freetype 2.x library: yes
Support for Fontconfig library: yes
Support for Xpm library: no
Support for liq library: no
Support for pthreads: yes
```

It looks good enough to me. But when I run the make, I get errors:

```
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
ld: malformed 64-bit a.b.c.d.e version number: 4.20201
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [libgd.la] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Since it was not working, I followed [this recommendation on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059211/error-installing-libgd-in-mac-10-9) and I ran

> brew install gd

(I had to update brew by doing

```
cd /usr/local/Library
git pull origin master
```

following [this answer on Stackoverflow](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/153790/184865).)

But I get an error:

```
Error: You must `brew link libpng freetype` before gd can be installed
```

And when I run 'brew link libpng freetype', I get another error:

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.21... 
Error: Could not symlink bin/libpng-config
Target /usr/local/bin/libpng-config
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/libpng-config'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite libpng

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run libpng
```

Any solution to finally be able to run Circos?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I solved the problem by changing the permissions in /usr/local:

> sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local

Following the [recommendations on brew webpage](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Troubleshooting.md#troubleshooting).

Once this was solved, I just installed GD in Perl, [as described in the last step in Paulo Nuin's post](http://zientzilaria.herokuapp.com/blog/2012/06/03/installing-circos-on-os-x/).